# Problemas com slideDown no jQuery

Tags: jquery, animação

Estou com um problema que não faço a mínima ideia do que pode ser, entendo bem pouco de jQuery, no remover eu consegui fazer a animação do `.slideUp()` mas no adicionar que é um `.append()` não consigo fazer funcionar já tentei várias formas e não vai, segue abaixo o link com os códigos.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ucD3/373/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O novo elemento deve vir oculto para o slideDown poder mostra-lo, adicione `display:none` em linha ou na classe do novo elemento:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the Add Filed button is clicked
    $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
        //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
        $(".lista").append('<div class="nomes" style="display:none"><input class="input-adicional" id="nome" name="nome[]" placeholder="Nome completo" type="text" /><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete"></a></div>');
        $(".nomes").slideDown("slow");
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $("body").prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function () {
        $(this).parent("div").slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove()    
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Jader deu certinho, abraço.